# Hide a Facebook tab based on user's location

Tags: facebook

We're developing a Canvas app that will have a tab when implemented on the fan page. The Tab will have the like gate. What we want to do, is restrict access based on location. So, Facebook users outside of the US wouldn't see the tab when the go the fan page.

This blog posts speaks to showing users different content based on location (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/394), but i don't want them to see the tab at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set demographic restrictions (i.e., location, age, etc.) issue an HTTP POST with an [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to

`https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?restrictions={“RESTRICTION_TYPE:VALUE”, …}`

ie:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?restrictions={"location":"US"}
```

Users who do not pass the restrictions will not see the tab.

More information at: [Facebook Developer Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574) & [Graph API: Application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/).

Answer (score 0):

When an application is accessed as a Tab on a Page (iFrame) Facebook Passes a signed request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request). You would be able to use that data to get the user's location. However, it might need further authentication to get that information.

Please refer to this question for a hack to find the user location through their IP:
[Getting user location on Facebook page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616231/getting-user-location-on-facebook-page-tab)

Anyway, as far as I know, you cannot remove the application all together, you have to show up 'some content' for the users who load the tab. I suggest that if you want to restrict page content to use the country restriction for the entire page. However, it might be impractical for your use case.